# ocr - optical character recognition image size/quality decrease

Tags: ocr

I have question about OCR, parsing text from image. I am making ANDROID application that uses google cloud api to parse text from image. Problem is that sending/uploading image takes too much time. So I though i could resize image or decrease image quality. But in that case, usually the ocr detection results are suffering. Can anyone please tell me best way to do it. Maybe someone knows whatsapp image compression or the best image file format (jpg,png), best quality decrease/images size decrease ratio or something like that.

Thaks in progress

Comment: If you are using android or you may take hints from this link from google developer   https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/network-xfer

Comment: yes this talks about some concepts of doing it, some of them I'm familiar with. But I need to programmatic example. I am doing it in android studio...